# Very bright cursos positions

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, potentiometer

[image]

As you may can I see on the picture. I try to display the word "goodbye". Yet the problem is that the cursor positions are to bright. I hooked up a 10k ohm potmeter to the Anode. To change the backlight. Is there a way to make the cursos positions less visible?

Kind Regards,

Q

Comment: Adjust the contrast pot that you should have wired in?

Comment: as the brightness of the blue backlight changes so do the cursos positions. In the end the cursor positions are equally as bright as the backlight

Comment: Which pot are you adjusting?

Comment: connected to the Anode (pin 15)

Comment: No, you should be adjusting the *other* pot. The *contrast* pot.

Comment: that one goes to ground on my setup

Comment: Well, there's your problem then. If you created the circuit properly you'd be able to adjust the contrast. As it is you have no control. Every tutorial I have ever seen has specified a pot for the contrast. They don't do that just for fun - they do it for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue fixed: I adjusted the Anode (pin15) instead of the contrast (pin3).

Look at the conversation between me and Majenko to see the realisation.